# How to return failed validation parameters to a rails model form that doesn't know what page it's on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a small contact request form that appears on nearly every page in a site.
The form submits to the RequestsController create method. If all goes well, the request is saved in the Requests table and an e-mail is sent. If validation fails, I would like to redirect back to the referrer page.

Here is my create action...

```
def create
  @request = Request.new(params[:request])
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])

  if @request.save
    PodsMailer.contact_request(@request, @location).deliver
    PodsMailer.contact_confirmation(@request, @location).deliver
    flash[:notice] = "Thanks! Your message was sent. We will contact you shortly."
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Errors -- please check the form"
    flash[:errors] = @request.errors
    redirect_to ??????
  end
end
```

My question is when validation fails, how do I redirect back to the referrer AND send the values entered into the form by the user? I can't use a named route because I don't know where the request is coming from.

"redirect_to :back" works fine by itself. But I can't figure out how to send parameters. The flash hash makes it through just fine. So there's got to be something simple I'm missing.

I have tried passing a params hash (:params => params[:request]) to every combination I can imagine of redirect_to with :back, url_for, request.referer... but with no luck.

I imagine there is some way to manually build the url and tack on query parameters, though I'm not exactly sure how to do that. But I was wondering if there is a Rails trick for passing parameters in this situation. Also, I'd like to implement a server-side solution before adding an AJAX solution.

Any help would be much appreciated. My first question here. Hopefully I've done this correctly.

Thanks--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best here is to use `AJAX` and validation on client (that don't mean to deny server vilidation).

But for you I suggest this hacky solution:

```
def create
  @request = Request.new(params[:request])
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])

  if @request.save
    PodsMailer.contact_request(@request, @location).deliver
    PodsMailer.contact_confirmation(@request, @location).deliver
    flash[:notice] = "Thanks! Your message was sent. We will contact you shortly."
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Errors -- please check the form"
    flash[:errors] = @request.errors
    referer = request.referer.gsub(/\?.*/, "")
    redirect_to referer + "?" + params[:request].map{|k,v| "request[#{k}]=#{v}"}.join("&")
  end
end
```

But now you should in your request form do something like this:

```
<%= form_for Request.new(params[:request]) do |f| %>
...
```

or remove it into controller

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought something like that might be my only non-AJAX option. AJAX it is.